# Vertical Align Social Buttons

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I have 4 social buttons at the top of my page, right above a Google search box, on https://www.romancestuck.com/kissing/types-of-kisses.htm. I can't seem to get the images to vertically align using margin or padding settings in CSS. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I meant that I want the social buttons in a horizontal row but I want them vertically aligned with each other too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following CSS code:

```
#social-buttons > span {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#social-buttons > span > * {
    vertical-align: middle !important;
}
```

I have used `!important` to force override the inline CSS of the `<div>` inside the `<span id="google-plus">`.

Comment: The question is about the website. So inspect those Social buttons in the website (using Firebug or any other tool) and test by adding the CSS code.

Comment: I have tried various margins and padding for the buttons but it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: @WebStuck Sorry for misunderstanding your question. I have rewritten the answer. I hope this is the answer for you.

Comment: That works! Thanks so much but could you please explain to me what #social-buttons > span > * does and why it is necessary? I understand that  #social-buttons > span references spans within the social-buttons div but I don't understand that > * part.

Comment: @WebStuck In my code, `*` refers to any element that is the child of the `<span>` element.